# Working with Different Time Speeds

Tags: java, android, time

There is a game where 10 minutes of real life equals 60 minutes on his day. **So one day in the game equals 4 hours in our real time.**

The user will inform me of the time of his game on his first time in the application, and I will need to show the game time to the user every time he enters the application. I tried doing this using a `SensorService` and a `BroadcastReceiver`, so that the calculation was always being done.

But since there is no way to get this time the same way we get the normal time, I had to do Background calculations to keep the time counting. This brought me trouble because the time was **NEVER** displayed accurately, not to mention the problem that is when the user has their cell phone turned off and everything.

I would really like to know if there is a simpler way to do this on Android, I'm new to this area and I do not know if there is a custom speed-time format or something. Thank you all at once.

Comment: its just `last_time (game) + (current_time (real) - last_time (game)) * 6`

Comment: this does not work, are you treating the data as if it were in milliseconds? @RandykaYudhistira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. save the first launch time(normal time).
2. on succeeding logins game time=(System.currentTimeinMilis() -first launch) * 6

Comment: Thanks, I did not know System.currentTimeinMillis (), you helped me soooo much